# What means SPSS syntax Error n° 10933 and how to resolve it?

Tags: syntax, aggregation, spss

I am currently running an aggregate function and I get :

Error n° 10933 in column 1. Text: DATASET
The definition of a new variable on the AGGREGATE command must be
terminated by a slash.
This command not executed.

I want to have the fertility ratio (Child-Woman ratio) from a 1911 census. Here is my syntax (I added the spaces here):

[Screen shot of the syntax here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xum2z.png)

I just don't understand why it cannot go through and adding slashes does not help either.

I seems to be a very banal error.

Does anyone have any advice ?

Thank you !

Comment: Insert a new blank line before you last line of code. Or put a full stop after your next to last line

Answer (score 1):

SPSS commands should be ended with periods. Your syntax treats the `DATASET ACTIVATE` as a continuation of the `AGGREGATE` command, and the parser thinks "DATASET" is a new variable. Put a period after the closed parentheses to finish the command.